# What does potential_conflict status mean in ISC dhcpd?

Tags: isc-dhcpd

We have two dhcpd running for a site as failover. Once, due to configuration file error, the primary knew secondary, but secondary did not know primary. After a few days, we noticed this and decided to bounce the secondary. Then we got potential_conflict. To resolve this, we bounced both dhcpd again.
The problem we met was that, before the second bouncing, all clients in the site lost their dynamic IP.
In my opinion, even bouncing both dhcpd is not a critical action for a running site. But this time, the whole site down for like 10 mins.

So, what does potential_conflict mean? And what caused the clients losing their IP?